# npm can't do (npm run dev) and give me this error below

Tags: php, npm, laravel-8

I use laravel framework and installed npm in my project but when I do this command `npm run dev` he gives me this error over and over. This is the first time he gives me that. I coding every day and this the first time I face this problem. BTW I have the last version of node.js

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($value, 255)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

    ╷
140 │     $value: if($value / 255 < .03928, $value / 255 / 12.92, nth($_luminance-list, $value + 1));
    │                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss 140:16             luminance()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss 124:8              contrast-ratio()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss 108:22             color-contrast()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_table-variants.scss 13:48  table-variant()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_tables.scss 133:3                 @import
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 22:9                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 8:9                                    root stylesheet
```

Comment: `luminance()` is that a function from your own code, or a plugin?

Comment: @aynber from a plugin

Comment: You might want to check for an update to that plugin or find a new one, since it's apparently not compatible. This is a warning and not a full error so shouldn't break anything for now, but it will in the future.

Comment: Maybe you should replace `$value / 255 < .03928` to `math.div($value, 255) < .03928` etc (and add `@use "sass:math";`). In the link in error description (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div) there are reasons for this.

Comment: @SergiyT. yes i open this link and see it but how i can replace all this things to ```math.div()```